# how to compute Bit Independent Criteria on a 4-bit S-box?

Tags: encryption, block-cipher, s-boxes, avalanche

The idea of Bit Independence Criterion (BIC ) was introduced by Webster and Tavares . For a given set of avalanche vectors generated by complementing a single plaintext bit, all avalanche variables should be pairwise independent. 
in https://peerj.com/preprints/26452/ Sankhanil Dey1 and Ranjan Ghosh2,introduce the computation on the s-box values instead of the avalanche values and said that it is balanced then BIC achieved. in this way all s boxes will satisfy BIC
table below illustrate the paper computation.
i think we have to find the avalanche first and the compute the all possible or total six xored 4-bit BFs on the avalanche vectors using the formula:
a+d/a+b+c+d
Here, a=(1,1), d=(0,0), b=(1,0), c=(0,1). [image] 
[image]

Comment: first table introduce what i think. second table which introduced in the paper. note different s-boxes are used.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: please ask a question.

Comment: @hardyrama, – kodlu How to compute the BIC?

Comment: @ kodlu, which vectors will be used, the avalanche vectors or the s-box vectors directly?