# how to compute Bit Independence criterion of SBOX?

Tags: encryption, aes, s-boxes

I want to compute BIC's of my Sboxes, I found out some theses for that but I could not understand how to do it. Can someone help me?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/61994/how-to-compute-bit-independent-criteria-on-a-4-bit-s-box

Comment: Most of the work is here: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/62128/how-to-compute-the-correlation-between-two-binary-vectors/62196#62196